# Why big loop in Java GUI lag/freeze?

Tags: java, swing, for-loop, ascii, jtextarea

I made a Java program that generate ASCII characters.

Here the following code if you want to try:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class asciiTable implements ActionListener {
    private static JButton exebouton;
    private JTextArea ecran = new JTextArea();
    private JScrollPane scrollecran = new JScrollPane(ecran);
    String line = "-------------";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new asciiTable();
    }

    private asciiTable() {
        // Window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Name");
        frame.setBounds(400, 350, 625, 355);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        Container container = frame.getContentPane();

        // Panel
        JPanel panneau = new JPanel();
        panneau.setLayout(null);
        panneau.setBounds(2, 42, 146, 252);
        frame.add(panneau);

        JLabel nglabel = new JLabel("Click");
        nglabel.setBounds(5, 0, 200, 20);
        panneau.add(nglabel);

        // Button
        exebouton = new JButton("Execute");
        exebouton.setBounds(4, 18, 138, 47);
        exebouton.addActionListener(this);
        panneau.add(exebouton);

        // Text Area
        ecran.setEditable(false);
        ecran.setLineWrap(true);
        scrollecran.setBounds(150, 42, 467, 252);
        container.add(scrollecran);

        // Show
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object test = e.getSource();    

        ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + line + '\n'
                    + "[ASCII TABLE]" + '\n'
                    + line + '\n');
        for (int i = 32, j = 0; i <= 800; i++, j++){ // WARNING: Big loop might lag your computer
            String putzero = "";
            if (i < 100){
                putzero = "0";
            }
            if (j >= 5){
                ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + "\n");
                j = 0;
            }
            ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + "[" + putzero + i + "] " + Character.toString ((char) i) + "\t");
        }
        ecran.setText(ecran.getText() + "\n");
    }

}
```

My question is: Why a big loop in Java GUI lags or freezes my computer? Is there a way to improve the speed?

Comment: does it freeze your entire computer, or just this one app?

Comment: @BryanOakley Just this app

Answer (score 3):

Actions in Swing should not be executed in the thread that is handling all the events.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Answer (score 2):

Swing is single threaded. You are performing a resource intensive action in the `EDT` preventing UI updates. Use one of Swing's [concurrency mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) to handle this functionality such as a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Answer (score 2):

You are looping in the Event Dispatch Thread. In this thread you are handling GUI paintings like setting the text in `JTextField`. This freezes the GUI and won't let any other action to be performed on GUI.If you want to perform long tasks then You should handle all such action events in separate Worker Threads like [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) or [`javax.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

Answer (score 1):

Consider to use a worker thread. After the thread finishes its work you can update the UI synchronously or asynchronously with the SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait() or SwingUtilities.invokeLater() method. The passed Runnable is executed in the UI thread, which enables you to update the UI in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing the looping in the GUI thread. You should handle it in another Thread that way, your GUI won't hung up.